# Is it possible to access the index in a for loop in vhdl ? error: indexed name prefix type natrual is not an array type

Tags: loops, vhdl, endianness

I want to write a small program that converts big endian to little endian. Therefore I need to use a for loop. Since I only want to do the switch every 8 bit (1 Byte) i need to use some kind of modulo. I am not a fan of using predefined methods and would like to write it as hardware near as possible. Therefore I wanted to access the iterator variable and check if the last three bits are zero. Thus, I know that 8 iterations are done. Saddy, I get the erro message:

> Indexed name prefix type natural is not an array type

My code is the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity TOP is
    Port ( INPUT : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (32 downto 0);
           CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
           OUTPUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (32 downto 0));

end TOP;

architecture Behavioral of TOP is

begin
S: process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        for I in INPUT' range loop
            --every 8 bit
            if I(3 downto 0) = "000" then
                OUTPUT(OUTPUT'left -I*8 downto OUTPUT'left - (I+1)*8) <= INPUT((I+1)*7 downto I*7); 
            end if;
        end loop;
    end if;
end process S;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now the obvious answer would be `if I mod 8 = 0 then` but you don't want to do that.

What you are doing with the line `if I(3 downto 0) = "000" then` is mixing levels of abstraction : an integer, and a low level representation of an integer as a bag of bits. Or strictly speaking, an indexable type - i.e. an array.

That is a bad idea because it makes assumptions about the representation fo an integer that may or may not be valid ... ironically, including endian-ness. So, VHDL won't let you do that.

What you can do is explicitly "convert" to a representation of an integer, where you can be certain what bit corresponds to what, and perform the low level operations on that concrete representation, instead of the abstract `Integer`. (Assuming the computer you're using has that representation anyway, the "conversion" has no penalty in time or hardware resources).

There are two standard such representations. in the `numeric_std` library, called `signed` and `unsigned` respectively. The 'signed' one is explicitly 2-s complement and the `unsigned` is straightforward - both are arrays of std_logic types, therefore indexable.

```
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
```

And you can read the source of this package, so there are no assumptions to make. (Or you could write a different package embodying the conventions you need instead. But nobody does that...)

So you could convert the loop variable to a 5-bit `unsigned` and index into that...

```
if to_unsigned(I,5)(2 downto 0) = "000" then
```

Note that the original comparison would ALWAYS return False because of the array length mismatch.

Finally, synthesis tools aren't stupid; they safely make the obvious optimisation on `mod` power-of-2 anyway.

Comment: While it is true that synthesis tools can make optimizations for on-target checks against mod power-of-2, that's irrelevant in this case. `I` will be a constant in the unrolled `for` loop during synthesis, and you can do any math you want on it as just the final calculated value will be baked into the netlist. Similarly with the `if` statement, because it depends entirely on constants, it will not result in multiplexers, but instead the synthesizer will use the result to decide whether to create hardware at all for the contained logic.

Comment: This whole block will be synthesized as a 32-bit register with no intermediate logic; the "conversion" is baked into which input pins are statically routed to which register bits. Because it contains no logic, there is actually no need for a register due to this block (although you may want one to break up the logic of whatever produces the input and whatever uses the output).